# Go back to (or convert) original string after some processings are done on it

Tags: c++, string

Because of a stringstream I get some data together and search in there for the smallest value. Before that each string goes through some processing.

```
void myMethod(std::experimental::filesystem::path pathOfImage) {

    string data; //this is the origin string, looks like: 0003(0.0, 45.0, -326.5)_dir1_Walls-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-1‌​8-19-20-21-22-23-24.‌​png
    double elem;
    list<double> someList;

    std::ifstream infile("SavedData.txt");
    while (std::getline(infile, data)) {
        std::istringstream iss(data);

        //extract substring from data and also pathOfImage
        //and I also convert both substrings to a vector<double>
        //...

        //calculation for elem, which is the distance between those vectors
        elem = vectors_distance(vec1, vec2);

        //add all elem to the list someList to pick the smallest one
        someList.push_back(elem);

        //a boolean method methodBool
        if (methodBool == true) {
            double minElem = *min_element(someList.begin(), someList.end());
            cout << "Minimum distance: " << minElem << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

As an output I get all the strings and the smallest value `minElem`of all off them.

Example: (doesn't matter what the first six numbers do)

```
0 45 -356.1 0 45 -390 33.9
0 45 -356.1 0 45 -326.5 29.6
Minimum Distance: 29.6
0 45 -356.1 0 45 -307.3 48.8
Minimum Distance: 29.6
0 45 -356.1 0 45 -289.7 66.4
Minimum Distance: 29.6
0 45 -356.1 0 45 -271.9 84.2
Minimum Distance: 29.6
```

So if the minimum distance is calculated, I *now* want it to be allocated to the origin string, for my example it'll be `0 45 -326.5` plus the extracted part (which will be the full string `data` -> see comment in code). How can I go back to the original string by refence to the `minElem`?

I'm happy about any help!

Comment: Perhaps you should read more about [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)? It is *supposed* to return "just a number".

Comment: Yes, it was just an idea, because I'm really don't know how to handle my problem.

Comment: Off-topic: don't compare booleans for `== true/false`. Prefer `if(methodBool)` instead - or `if(!methodBool)`, if need inverse check - even if it is a function - but you need to *call* it then (`if(methodBool  ()  )`)

Comment: "`0 45 -326.5` plus the extracted part" - So you want to *append* some information? If this information is a string already, you have `std::string::operator+=`. Otherwise, you could use an `std::ostringstream` for.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for the tip for comparing booleans.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, this information already was appended to the string, and I extracted it. And yes it is a string, too. Could you make an example for those both functions please?

Comment: @Unnamed Sorry, don't really get what you actually want to do. Something like this: `std::string data; std::string extracted = get(data); (data += ' ') += extracted;`? So the final string will contain the extracted data twice, second time possibly modified?

Comment: @Aconcagua okay, I'll try to make a better example:
`string data` is my original string, it looks like `0003(0.0, 45.0, -326.5)_dir1_Walls-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24.png`. In the processing I'm removing everything I won't need in the further steps, so there's remaining only the substring `(0.0, 45.0, -326.5)`. Now I'm extracting only all `double`s.

Comment: @Aconcagua after finding the minimum, I'll get the output above. 
All I want to do now is to geht back the whole `string data`, which is `0003(0.0, 45.0, -326.5)_dir1_Walls-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-1‌​8-19-20-21-22-23-24.‌​png`

Comment: @Unnamed I see - you don't want to reconstruct a string, you want to get back the one string that produced the minimum - is that right?

Comment: @Aconcagua exactly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments: There is quite some easy way: Use a `std::map`. The map keeps its entries sorted, so you only need to get the map's begin()...

```
std::map<double, std::string> elements; // instead of somelist!

std::string data;
while (std::getline(infile, data))
{
    double elem = ...;

    elements[elem] = data;
}

std::string minPath = elements.begin()->second;
```

Done...

One point left, though: Above algorithm will, if some data strings produce by accident exactly the same distance, only retain the *last* data string found. If you want to keep the first one, you need to use `insert` function instead. If you want to keep *all* data strings and select among these with another algorithm, you need to use `std::multi_map`.

Much simpler, if you do not need any further data:

```
std::string minPath;
double minVal = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

std::string data;
while (std::getline(infile, data))
{
    double elem = ...;

    if(elem < minVal)
    {
        minVal = elem;
        minPath = data;
    }
}

// use minPath...
```

Comment: what is `minPath`?

Comment: tried it, but I get all strings not the one with the smallest data

Comment: What do you mean by "all strings"? `minPath` is one single string in both variants.

Comment: Do you possibly mix up "output" and "result"? If you leave the `cout <<` part *within* the loop, you get the current minimum printed out with every new line read (provided methodBool returns true...), which is the output, the result, however, is stored in minPath...

Comment: @Aconcagua That's strange: even though `methodBool` returns true, after `if(dust < minVal)` I'm getting a value which isn't true for `methodBool`. This happens since I tried your code.

Comment: @Unnamed Arrgh... SORRY: Did not adjust minVal in previous code!!! This is, of course, *very* important! See fixed code...

Comment: @Aconcagua still the same issue. If you want we could talk in chat?

Comment: after debugging it acually tracks the right one, but return a false one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149798/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-unnamed).

Comment: @Aconcagua get it! My mistake was, that I still had `std::string minPath = elements.begin()->second;` in my code written.